# Logstash split fields

Tags: filter, split, logstash

Actually im trying to split a field's request with `&` caracter

```
kv {
      source => "request"
      field_split => "&?"
      target => "params"
 }
```

For example when the request is:

```
toto=a&titi=b$tata=c
```

I get this:

```
{
    "toto":"a",
    "titi":"b",
    "tata":"c",
}
```

But same times the value of field contains the `&` caracter like:

```
toto=a&titi=b$tata=c..tt&d=lolo
```

Then with my filter i will get:

```
{
    "toto":"a",
    "titi":"b",
    "tata":"cc..tt",
    "d":"lolo"
}
```

Or i want to get:

```
{
    "toto":"a",
    "titi":"b",
    "tata":"c..tt&d=lolo"
}
```

Is there any solution to intercept `c..tt&d=lolo` as a value of `tata` ?

B.R

Comment: Is the format of the special case easy to predict? does it always happen with one particular value? Otherwise this could be quite challenging, if not impossible. You are asking a tool that simply splits on a character and then splits on `=` to not do that, seemingly arbitrarily. If there is a pattern for when this case would come up, then you may be able to do this

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately there is no special cases to predict, it seems impossible because i cant find a tool that helps me. I want to extract the parameters from this requests but the `owa_HTTP_REFERER` field contains `&` caracter so at the end the `k` tool reterns also the other parameters of the field. `owa_page_url=http://www.toto.com/&owa_page_title=tototitle&owa_event_type=base.page_request&owa_HTTP_REFERER=http://fr.search.yahoo.com/search?rewrite=72&.tsrc=apple&first=1&p=les+indicateurs+economiques&pintl=fr&pcarrier=F+SFR&pmcc=208&pmnc=10&fr=onesearchnew&tsrc=apple&owa_cv1=isfl=1`

Comment: is it always the owa_HTTP_REFERRER field? If so you could just grab it before you kv's the rest of the params